# Is it possible to repeat one div several times in flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create some windows on a house, this house has 30 windows. I wondered if it would be possible to create it using only one div and repeating it?

Comment: not with CSS. You need at least JS for that and then use a `for`-loop and generate the content dynamically

Answer (score 2):

Good Morning! With CSS only you cant make it generic. CSS in combination with JS will help you to archive this goal. Take a look to the example below:

```js
const h = document.querySelector('.h');
const wc = 30;

for(let i = 0; i < wc; i++) {
  const w = document.createElement('div');
  
  h.append(w);
}
```

```css
.h {
  background-color: brown;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding:10px;
}
.h div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.h div:after {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div class="h"></div>
```